# How to request the "load more" function with Python?

Tags: python, urllib2, python-requests

Hi~I'm now doing my research on Zhihu, a Chinese Q&A website like Quora, using social network analysis. And I'm writing a crawler with Python these days, but met a problem:

I want to scratch the user info that follows a specific user, like Kaifu-Lee. The Kaifu-Lee's followers page is http://www.zhihu.com/people/kaifulee/followers
And the load-more button is at the bottom of the followers list, I need to get full list.

Here's the way I do with python requests:

```
import requests
import re

s = requests.session()
login_data = {'email': '***', 'password': '***', }

# post the login data.
s.post('http://www.zhihu.com/login', login_data)

# verify if I've login successfully. Surely this step have succeed.
r = s.get('http://www.zhihu.com')
```

Then, I jumped to the target page:

```
r = s.get('http://www.zhihu.com/people/kaifulee/followers')
```

and get 200 return:

```
In [7]: r
Out[7]: <Response [200]>
```

So the next step is to analyze the request of load-more under "network" tag using chrome's developer tool, here's the information:

```
Request URL: http://www.zhihu.com/node/ProfileFollowersListV2
Request Method: POST

Request Headers
  Connection:keep-alive
  Host:www.zhihu.com
  Origin:http://www.zhihu.com
  Referer:http://www.zhihu.com/people/kaifulee/followers

Form data
  method:next
  params:{"hash_id":"12135f10b08a64c54e8bfd537dd7bee7","order-by":"created","offset":20}
  _xsrf:ea63beee3a3444bfb853f36b7d968ad1
```

So I try to POST:

```
global header_info
header_info = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1581.2 Safari/537.36',
    'Host':'www.zhihu.com',
    'Origin':'http://www.zhihu.com',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Referer':'http://www.zhihu.com/people/zihaolucky/followers',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }

# form data.
data = r.text
raw_hash_id = re.findall('hash_id(.*)',data)
hash_id = raw_hash_id[0][14:46]

payload={"method":next,"hash_id":str(hash_id),"order_by":"created","offset":20}

# post with parameters.
url = 'http://www.zhihu.com/node/ProfileFollowersListV2'
r = requests.post(url,data=payload,headers=header_info)
```

BUT, it returns Response<404>>

If I made any mistake?

**Someone said I made a mistake in dealing with the params. The Form Data has 3 parameters:`method`,`params`,`_xsrf`and I lost `_xsrf` and then I put them into a dictionary.**

**So I modified the code:**

```
# form data.
data = r.text
raw_hash_id = re.findall('hash_id(.*)',data)
hash_id = raw_hash_id[0][14:46]
raw_xsrf = re.findall('xsrf(.*)',r.text)
_xsrf = raw_xsrf[0][9:-3]


payload = {"method":"next","params":{"hash_id":hash_id,"order_by":"created","offset":20,},"_xsrf":_xsrf,}

# reuse the session object, but still error.
>>> r = s.post(url,data=payload,headers=header_info)
>>> <Response [500]>
```

Comment: You sure you got the URL right? I'm not seeing where the `url` variable comes from in your code.

Comment: Hi~ I've jumped to the target page: `r = s.get('http://www.zhihu.com/people/kaifulee/followers')` And now I need to post the `url: http://www.zhihu.com/node/ProfileFollowersListV2`

Comment: is "scrapy" tags relevant?

Comment: @pault. haha, any hint? I tried Scrapy before but have no idea.

Comment: I think you might need to use a session and can't access the "view more" directly. Also, assuming xsrf works like csrf, you'll need to pass a Referer URL too

Comment: Why aren't you reusing your session? It's almost certainly the case that you need to be logged in to access that data.

Comment: @Lukasa Yep, reusing the session object is right, but also return 500 error. Almost gonna crazy ><

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass nested dictionaries to the `data` parameter. Requests just doesn't know what to do with them.

It's not clear, but it looks like the value of the `params` key is probably JSON. This means your payload code should look like this:

```
params = json.dumps({"hash_id":hash_id,"order_by":"created","offset":20,})
payload = {"method":"next", "params": params, "_xsrf":_xsrf,}
```

Give that a try.